# my app crashes if i change views whilst downloading data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous

I have a tableview based app that downloads rss feeds from the web. So i have view1, i click a row in the table and the results show on view2. This works great but if i change back to view1 while the data is being downloaded. It crashes!

Any ideas what i need to change (its nsxmlparser by the way)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more information about the problem would be useful to understand what's going on, but based on what you posted my guess would be that you are setting a `delegate` for something (the `NSXMLParser` or the url connection, or maybe something else) and when you go back to `view1`, `view2` gets destroyed, destroying the delegate object and leaving whoever it was with a dangling `delegate` pointer.

Comment: Yep, filipe's answers sounds to point in the right direction. When you go back (assuming it is a navigation controller) either set the delegate to nil, or even better make sure the download/parsing is aborted and released, so the navigation controller can be allowed to properly tear down your view. You can only count on the viewDidAppear/willAppear and viewWill/DidDisapper messages are sent, not the viewDidUnload or dealloc, the navigationController can choose to have your view hanging around. So put "must be run once" code in "viewDidLoad" and "must run every time view appears" in viewWill..